# PDF Created using iTextsharp throwing error

Tags: itext

I'm trying to create a pdf file by combining multiple jpg images using iTextsharp.Its coming up good but in some pdfs error is popping up as 'internal error occured' and image is not visible on page. pls assist.

```
Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(outputpath, FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();
foreach (string name in imagename)
{
    string imagePath = ImageLocation + name;
    iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
    doc.SetPageSize(image);
    doc.NewPage();
    image.SetAbsolutePosition(0,0);
    doc.Add(image);
}
doc.Close();
```

Comment: This question can't be answered without you providing the error message that is thrown and/or the image that causes the problem. For instance: maybe `imagePath` isn't referring to an actual image. In that case, an exception is thrown. You should add a try/catch *inside* the `foreach` or else your PDF will fail everytime `imagePath` is wrong. If `imagePath` is valid, it may be referring to a file that is not a valid image. In that case, you have a problem too. Also: which version of iTextSharp are you using? Older versions had some problems with specific images. Show us one of the bad PDFs.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Thanks for the info. Yes, its problem related to the images.

Comment: OK, so now we need to see a specific image, create a PDF with it using a recent iText version and see what's the exact problem with it. Otherwise, we just searching for an answer in the dark.